# Вывод модального окна только один раз Jquery

Tags: jquery

Вообщем сам сайт тут http://vaishnav.ga/recomm/

Там если увести курсор в верх то появится модальное окно. Мне нужно что бы это окно после первого появления уже больше не появлялось.

Понимаю чо это счечик и не так сложно. Но голова уже не варит, помогите кто чем сможет.

Это код вывода модального окна.

Само модальное окно это magnificPopup.

```
 $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

if(e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop() <= 10){ 

    // Launch MODAL BOX
    $.magnificPopup.open({
     items: {
     src: '#pop-after-registration-2'
        },
    type: 'inline'

        }, 0);
    }

});

});
```

Comment: Прошу обратить ваше внимание на топик  [Союз «чтобы» («чтоб») пишется слитно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5666/191482) и в целом о правилах...И да — это важно и имеет значение.

Comment: По самому вопросу: нужно, чтобы не появлялось в данной сессии или вообще больше никогда? Ибо есть вариант просто с флагом, а есть с куки/localStorage

Comment: Спасибо, за урок грамматики - иногда как видете голова не варит.

Comment: Нужно было просто после первого появление без куков.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так попробуй. Делаешь проверку, если уже открывалось, больше не откроется.

```js
var isShown = false;

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  if (!isShown) {

    if (e.pageY - $(document).scrollTop() <= 10) {

      // Launch MODAL BOX
      $.magnificPopup.open({
        items: {
          src: '#pop-after-registration-2'
        },
        type: 'inline'
      }, 0);

      isShown = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает.